# Decode Footer Link

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink, decode

i have a free theme on my wordpress. but it have links on its footer. and when i see its footer.php i see only like this..:

```
<?php eval(stripslashes(gzinflate(base64_decode("dVLLboMwEDwTKf+wyqEhF7g3lKh/UCWRqkpIyOAltgQY2U5IpH58/YBAk5YL652dnd2xd+lyAbNvOiUx5ZcBHePlIkhMBJy+ZatC0Fsu+YnpbDXrMhUoTrEgMidUmYpk17EOeBVW57bUXLQ5XrnSKszWmmGDtixXTPTZerOB36lws4VdOk4RBE8ayo0QGMSpnFDnA+KpjjTSp23G6PFvortCJYRG6fs/ZnON19n2L6XoblvwM2DJBFCiMfxyI0BCfI5JrEwHX1XU4sTbShgXzrI2q9vSu1sztCUNDnASkzQCeK9r2Fv7FexRobwgjeAbjtY5+JDiYgygUNzc7mSUZVp3r3Hc933UdxobwlvKZVSKxqh+Ckk7iUrB0SBWxzT8l69EWxBGJG8G+gFVzeEgWIHakp0tz966hm6/vsu9keMt/XkprtQ/CN1zbX2fHoVn2LfoKEw3tTHvBw==")))); ?>
```

how can i remove these links and add my own link over there???

Comment: @Gordon this looks rather like a code block built in by the Theme's author, in a  feeble attempt to prevent jokers like this guy from changing the copyright notice in it

Comment: @Pekka Feeble, but apparently not unsuccessful.

Answer (score 5):

Like others already pointed out in the comments, the author of the theme apparently tried to prevent you from changing the footer on purpose. **You have to check with the theme's license agreement or contact the theme's author whether you may remove the copyright notice**. Just because you did not have to pay for the theme, does not mean you may modify it. It says "All rights reserved" for a reason.

You can see the actual footer code by not `eval`ing but `echo`ing it, e.g.

```
echo stripslashes(gzinflate(base64_decode("dVLLboMwEDwTKf+[...]THvBw==")));
```

This will give you the footer's PHP code. **If you are allowed to modify this code**, you have to replace the original footer code with the modified version.

**Sidenote:** both the footer div and the div it contains have IDs, so you could just as well [hide the links with CSS](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/display). That would be less invasive, though it doesn't change that you should ask for permission first.

Comment: i can see links on my site already.. so what does echo mean?? i have permission to remove that so dont worry.. i know guy who design it but cant contact him now..    

i just want to delete it from my site.. how???

i deleted eval and write echo there and save.. but nothisng change.. i can still see link in my site..

Comment: @curious To be honest *"i know guy who design it but cant contact him now"* does not sound too convincing to me. Please bear with me if I dont give you any copy and paste code to infringe on other people's intellectual property. My answer contains two possible solutions and all the hints you need to know to get this working. Like Pekka already said, if you really know the author, ask him or her for help. If you cannot reach the author *now*, maybe you can tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

it happened many times that this kind of encrypted footer contained malware.
so, everybody should be instructed to decode it.

generally speaking, encryption is *not* a way to stop piracy. good quality themes and good business model are a way to limit piracy (just look at themeforest and their business model that's actually working)

thank you and sorry if I'm OT